# Weird result from "@SuppressWarnings"

Tags: java, annotations, suppress-warnings

Eclipse was warning me that a local variable randInt might not be initialized (it was). So I added the first line:

```
@SuppressWarnings("all")
return randInt;
```

The warning went away, but I'm getting two new errors on the first line: 
Syntax error: insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeaderName, and 
Syntax error: insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatement

What on earth? It's surprisingly hard to find information about @SuppressWarnings. Is there a more precise way of getting rid of this specific warning than using "all"?

Minimal, complete, verifiable example:

```
public class SuppressTest {
    public int cut() { 
        int randInt = 0; 
        @SuppressWarnings("all") 
        return randInt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Wait, I see this method has the same name as a boolean instance variable "cut" (which is set to true immediately before the @SuppressWarnings). Is this legal in Java? Could that be the issue? Code runs OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't insert `@SuppresWarnings` on a return statement. In java 8 you can annotate only classes, methods/constructors, fields, parameters and (new in java 8) local variables.

So in your case java can't parse what you have written. Move the `@SuppressWarnings` at the method level.

Comment: Thanks. Part 2 of my question: is there a specific type of warning that targets the "variable may not have been initialized" message?